# Accumulated sum per quarter

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I've tried several ways to calculated the accumulated sum per quarter for the following table in Power BI, but I couldn't get the right results.

What I need is to sum the "% increase" column per quarter but resetting when the quarter changes.

Can anybody help me out with this?

I don't need the blank spaces as long as the results I get is per quarter.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9EUS.png)

Thanks.

I've tried to use calculate with dateadd, parallelperiod, previous quarter, etc and none of it worked.

Comment: A good alternative can be, you add a new column with value like - Q1_2021, Q2_2002. Now use the Quarter column instead of date column in your visual and in the measure you apply any aggregation you need to get your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Acc = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Tabela[%] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Tabela[Date] ),
        QUARTER ( Tabela[Date] )
            = ROUNDUP ( MONTH ( MAX ( Tabela[Date] ) ) / 3, 0 )
    )
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APc8v.png)